# Color Ramp alignment

Tags: texturing, texture-coordinates

I have a Color Ramp node that I'd like to go vertically up a default cube.
The cube hasn't been rotated, just raised on Z to a value of 1. Why is the ramp placement not defaulting to either a vertical or horizontal alignment? I could play with the rotation settings on the Mapping node, but even then it's not a perfect 45 or 90 degree setting.

[image: default cube with color ramp applied]

Comment: It's because you connected a vector (dark blue) socket to a float (gray) socket, which averages the XYZ components I think. Put a Separete XYZ node in between and feed its Z output into the Color Ramp.

Comment: That works! If you post as an answer I'd be happy to give it to you. Also, any idea how to make the gradient span out farther? It's a fairly abrupt transition, I'd like it to be smoother.

Comment: @Increality for that, I would say a gradient node would be better, you can map it more easily also and can also change the type.